# Arduino SPWM generating

Tags: arduino

I saw this post, generating SPWM with Arduino and then I saw filtering the SPWM signal with RC filter to get sine wave. A question: how can I calculate the values ​​for R and C, and if we use LC how can I calculate L and C?
Thank you

ref GitHub - Irev-Dev/Arduino-Atmel-sPWM: Implementation of an sPWM signal

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: Nota : please, give a link for reference. Thanks. If you want drive a H-Bridge, forget R-C network at power output. You need "only" knowing the PWM frequency ... if it does not change.

Comment: Searching for "first order filter design" should give you all you need.